# file globbing in bash not being picked up by php -l

Tags: bash, php, wildcards

I am trying to run php's `lint` function on all files in a directory, and it's proving to be harder than I expected. (I know there are non-php files here; I'm not concerned about that right now.) Here's what I've tried:

```
$> php -l *
No syntax errors detected in embeddedlabels.js
$> php -l \*
Could not open input file: *
$> ls *
embeddedlabels.js  README.txt  myfile.admin.inc  myfile.css  myfile.info  myfile.install  myfile.js  myfile.module
$> php -l $(ls *)
No syntax errors detected in embeddedlabels.js
```

Based on [the documentation here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html), I tried this:

```
$> echo *
embeddedlabels.js README.txt myfile.admin.inc myfile.css myfile.info myfile.install myfile.js myfile.module

$> php -l $(echo *)
No syntax errors detected in embeddedlabels.js
```

But still no luck. How do I do this?

Comment: This has the appearance of `php -l` only processing one file at a time. Perhaps you need a loop?

Comment: appears so - see: http://stefaanlippens.net/php-lint-multiple-files-parallel

Comment: Ah -- `for i in $(ls *) ; do php -l $i; done`-- no less verbose method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell globbing was (most likely) succeeding, and was passing the files to `php -l`, but `php -l` only processes one file at a time ([ref](http://stefaanlippens.net/php-lint-multiple-files-parallel)). One of the shortest (not bullet-proof) ideas I have:

```
for f in *; do php -l "$f"; done
```

Modify the `*` to be `*.js` or whatever other extension you might use. For multiple extensions, just pile them in:

```
for f in *.js *.inc *.module; do php -l "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid a loop, you can use `xargs`:

```
ls * | xargs -I{} php -l {}
```

It wouldn't work for files with newlines in their names.

Comment: would just need `-n 1` (or `-1`) here because of how `php -l` behaves -- processing only one file at a time, regardless of how many you pass it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: That's what `-I` does: it implies `-L1`.